# need to retrieve result set of Join Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Need to retrieve result set of both tables but i am getting null value in it

```
var Items = from t1 in dbModal.Table1
            join t2 in dbModal.Table2 on t1.id equals t2.Id
            select new 
            { t1, t2.column };
```

**need to map above query like  this**

```
Select t1.*,t2.Column from T1
join T2 on T1.id=T2.Id
```

Comment: Show us how tables look like and the real linq you use. This is not enough to determine the problem

Comment: You will get nulls if id is in t1 but not in t2.  See left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: if i am writing a query directly in SQL server it works Fine.

but  there is some issue with t2. dont know how to access it

Comment: which version of ef are you using ?